# Problem with font registration in Canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js

I'm trying to register a font in canvas in order to upload the bot to hosting, I don't get any errors, but the font is simply not displayed on the host. Here is the code

```
const { AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const Canvas = require('@napi-rs/canvas');

const { registerFont } = require('canvas');
registerFont('./Comic Sans MS.ttf', { family: 'Comic Sans' })

const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1150, 800);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./image.png');
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = '#270a1f';
        ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.height - 400, canvas.width, 400);
 
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff033e';
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = '#0000ff'
        ctx.beginPath();
```

what do I enter to make the font appear

```
ctx.font = '50px "Comic Sans"';
 ctx.fillStyle = '#412227';
```

I looked through the documentation and didn't find any obvious errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some systems `./` is the `current working directory` instead of the file directory.
Instead use `process.cwd()` or the `path` module.

```js
registerFont(`${process.cwd()}/path/Comic Sans MS.ttf`, { family: 'Comic Sans' })
```

```js
const { resolve } = require("path")
registerFont(resolve('./Comic Sans MS.ttf'), { family: 'Comic Sans' })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try importing `GlobalFonts` from `@napi-rs/canvas`, and then using `GlobalFonts.registerFromPath()`.

This is my code, which works fine for me:

```js
import { GlobalFonts } from '@napi-rs/canvas';
// or require for JS

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

GlobalFonts.registerFromPath(
    resolve(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'Segoe_UI.ttf'),
    'Segoe UI'
);

ctx.font = '700 20px Segoe UI';
```